# how to enable hot reload in newly created vue js project?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I am new to Vuejs. I have created a Vuejs project, but I have to re-run the project each time to reflect the changes  in browser. The project is created by(default vue 3)

```
vue create projectname
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Look into VITE. It's made by the same guy who made vuejs. It does what you're asking about with Hot module replacement (changes made show up instantly in the browser). It's amazing. I'm not sure if you can update an existing project to use vite, but it's dead easy to start a new vue3 project with vite.